# How to Make Sitcky Item in Select List?

Tags: entities

I've got a Select List, let's say Apple, Orange, Raspberry. TBD.

I need TBD to be sticky at top of the list, while the other items are sorted alphabetically.

Recommendations on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option you want to consider, you could use a convention for your select list values like so:

- 01-Apple.
- 02-Orange.
- 03-Raspberry.
- 00-TBD.

The sorted version of this list would look like so:

- 00-TBD.
- 01-Apple.
- 02-Orange.
- 03-Raspberry.

It's what I often do for any software where I somehow want to overrule the whatever sorting (eg to ensure my most often used folder names are always at the top) ... And it works in pretty much every OS I ever used (including mainframes ...)